# How much faster are SSE4.2 string instructions than SSE2 for memcmp?

Tags: assembly, x86, sse, micro-optimization, sse4

Here is my code's assembler

Can you embed it in c ++ and check against SSE4? At speed

I would very much like to see how stepped into the development of SSE4. Or is not worried about him at all? Let's check (I do not have support above SSSE3)

```
{ sse2 strcmp WideChar 32 bit }
function CmpSee2(const P1, P2: Pointer; len: Integer): Boolean;
asm
    push ebx           // Create ebx
    cmp EAX, EDX      // Str = Str2
    je @@true        // to exit true
    test eax, eax   // not Str
    je @@false     // to exit false
    test edx, edx // not Str2
    je @@false   // to exit false
    sub edx, eax              // Str2 := Str2 - Str;
    mov ebx, [eax]           // get Str 4 byte
    xor ebx, [eax + edx]    // Cmp Str2 4 byte
    jnz @@false            // Str <> Str2 to exit false
    sub ecx, 2            // dec 4
    { AnsiChar  : sub ecx, 4 }
    jbe @@true           // ecx <= 0 to exit true
    lea eax, [eax + 4]  // Next 4 byte
    @@To1:
    movdqa xmm0, DQWORD PTR [eax]       // Load Str 16 byte
    pcmpeqw xmm0, DQWORD PTR [eax+edx] // Load Str2 16 byte and cmp
    pmovmskb ebx, xmm0                // Mask cmp
    cmp ebx, 65535                   // Cmp mask
    jne @@Final                     // ebx <> 65535 to goto final
    add eax, 16                    // Next 16 byte
    sub ecx, 8                    // Skip 8 byte (16 wide)
    { AnsiChar  : sub ecx, 16 }
    ja @@To1                     // ecx > 0
    @@true:                       // Result true
    mov eax, 1                 // Set true
    pop ebx                   // Remove ebx
    ret                      // Return
    @@false:                  // Result false
    mov eax, 0             // Set false
    pop ebx               // Remove ebx
    ret                  // Return
    @@Final:
    cmp ecx, 7         // (ebx <> 65535) and (ecx > 7)
    { AnsiChar : cmp ecx, 15 }
    jae @@false       // to exit false
    movzx ecx, word ptr @@mask[ecx * 2 - 2] // ecx = mask[ecx]
    and ebx, ecx                           // ebx = ebx & ecx
    cmp ebx, ecx                          // ebx = ecx
    sete al                              // Equal / Set if Zero
    pop ebx                             // Remove ebx
    ret                                // Return
    @@mask: // array Mersenne numbers
    dw $000F, $003F, $00FF, $03FF, $0FFF, $3FFF
    { AnsiChar
    dw 7, 15, 31, 63, 127, 255, 511, 1023, 2047, 4095, 8191, 16383
    }
end;
```

Semple 32bit  https://vk.com/doc297044195_451679410

Comment: Is that Delphi asm or something?  It doesn't look like any C++ inline-asm syntax I've ever seen.

Comment: My code works very fast! And it has all the optimizations for the better. I wanted to see tests with SSE4

Yes .. I wrote on Delphi

Comment: Sure, it's pretty good, but it could be faster.  Anyway, this is not a good question for Stack Overflow.  We don't accept "please benchmark this code" questions, and we definitely don't accept "please write an SSE4 version of this and benchmark it".  You didn't say which microarchitectures you care about (e.g. tuning for Nehalem is different from tuning for Ryzen), and you didn't say whether you care more about short or long strings.

Comment: @PeterCordes, what is Delphi and Delphi asm? I have never heard of them

Comment: There's no need to use naked pointers. A simple `const S1,S2: string` will give you the same pointer but in a type safe way. And then you do not need the len parameter.

Comment: @Zboson: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delphi_(programming_language).  It's the successor to Borland Turbo Pascal.  I've never used it, but I recognize the `{ }` and other parts of the style from some other SO posts.

Comment: The first 4B test `xor ebx, [eax + edx]` -> if string is only single char, are there's junk after it in memory, this will fail to detect identical strings. (like memory content `['a', 0, 0, 1]` vs `['a', 0, 0, 0]` when both strings have length 1, so that memory represents string `"a"`). Does your Pascal guarantee there will be no junk after the end of string? Not sure how to test, maybe creating two strings "aaa", "abb", shortening them both to length 1, then comparing (if the truncating function doesn't clear memory, or copy the new string to new memory, then you are in trouble).Feels fragile

Answer (score 14):

You called your function `strcmp`, but what you've actually implemented is an alignment-required `memcmp(const void *a, const void *b, size_t words)`.  Both `movdqa` and `pcmpeqw xmm0, [mem]` will fault if the pointer isn't 16B-aligned.  (Actually, if `a+4` isn't 16B-aligned, because you do the first 4 scalar and increment by 4 bytes.)

With the right startup code and `movdqu`, you could handle arbitrary alignments (reaching an alignment boundary for the pointer you want to use as a memory operand to `pcmpeqw`).  For convenience, you could require that both pointers are wide-char-aligned to start with, but you don't need to (especially since you're just returning true/false, not `negative / 0 / 
positive` as a sort order.)

---

You're asking about performance of SSE2 `pcmpeqw` vs. `pcmpistrm`, right?  (The explicit-length SSE4.2 instructions like [`pcmpestrm` have worse throughput than the implicit-length versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20935769/sse42-sttni-pcmpestrm-is-twice-slower-than-pcmpistrm-is-it-true), so use the implicit-length versions in your main loop when you're not close to the end of the string.  See [Agner Fog's instruction tables](http://agner.org/optimize/) and microarch guide).

**For memcmp (or carefully-implemented strcmp), the best you can do with SSE4.2 is slower than the best you can do with SSE2 (or SSSE3) on most CPUs**.  Maybe useful for very short strings, but not for the main loop of memcmp.

On Nehalem: `pcmpistri` is 4 uops, 2c throughput (with a memory operand), so with no other loop overhead, it can keep up with memory.  (Nehalem only has 1 load port).  `pcmpestri` has 6c throughput: 3x slower.

On Sandybridge through Skylake, `pcmpistri xmm0, [eax]` has 3c throughput, so it's a factor of 3 too slow to keep up with 1 vector per clock (2 load ports).  `pcmpestri` has 4c throughput on most of those, so it's not as much worse.  (Maybe useful for the last partial-vector, but not in the main loop).

On Silvermont/KNL, `pcmpistrm` is the fastest, and runs at one per 14 cycle throughput, so it's total garbage for simple stuff.

On AMD Jaguar, `pcmpistri` is 2c throughput, so it might actually be usable (only one load port).  `pcmpestri` is 5c throughput, so it sucks.

On AMD Ryzen,  `pcmpistri` is also 2c throughput, so it's crap there.  (2 load ports and 5 uops per clock front-end throughput (or 6 uops if any (or all?) are from multi-uop instructions) mean you can go faster.

On AMD Bulldozer-family, `pcmpistri` has 3c throughput until Steamroller, where it's 5c.  `pcmpestri` has 10c throughput.  They're micro-coded as 7 or 27 m-ops, so AMD didn't spend a lot of silicon on them.

**On most CPUs, they're only worth it if you're taking full advantage of them for stuff you can't do with just `pcmpeq`/`pmovmskb`**.  But if you can use AVX2 or especially AVX512BW, even doing complicated things might be faster with more instructions on wider vectors.  (There are no wider versions of the SSE4.2 string instructions.)  Maybe the SSE4.2 string instructions are still useful for functions that usually deal with short strings, because wide vector loops usually need more startup / cleanup overhead.  Also, in a program that doesn't spend much time in SIMD loops, using AVX or AVX512 in one small function will still reduce your max turbo clock speed for the next millisecond or so, and could easily be a net loss.

---

A good inner loop should bottleneck on load throughput, or come as close as possible.  `movqdu` / `pcmpeqw [one-register]` / `pmovmskb`/ macro-fused-cmp+jcc is only 4 fused-domain uops, so this is almost achievable on Sandybridge-family CPUs

---

See https://www.strchr.com/strcmp_and_strlen_using_sse_4.2 for an implementation and some benchmarks, but that's for C-style implicit-length strings where you have to check for `0` bytes.  It looks like you're using explicit-length strings, so after checking that the lengths are equal, it's just `memcmp`.  (Or I guess if you need to find the sort order instead of just equal / not-equal, you'd have to memcmp out to the end of the shorter string.)

For strcmp with 8-bit strings, on most CPUs it's faster not to use the SSE4.2 string instructions. See the comments on the strchr.com article for some benchmarks (of that implicit-length string version).  glibc for example doesn't use the SSE4.2 string instructions for `strcmp`, because they're not faster on most CPUs.  They might be a win for `strstr` though.

---

glibc has several SSE2/SSSE3 asm `strcmp` and [`memcmp` implementations](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/sysdeps/x86_64/memcmp.S.html#117).  (It's LGPLed, so you can't just copy it into non-GPL projects, but have a look at what they do.)  Some of the string functions (like strlen) only branch per 64 bytes, and then come back to sort out which byte within the cache line had the hit.  But their memcmp implementation just unrolls with movdqu / `pcmpeqb`.  You can use `pcmpeqw` since you want to know the position of the first 16-bit element that's different, rather than the first byte.

---

Your SSE2 implementation could be even faster.  You should use the indexed addressing mode with movdqa since it won't micro-fuse with pcmpeqw (on Intel Sandybridge/Ivybridge; fine on Nehalem or Haswell+), but `pcmpeqw xmm0, [eax]` will stay micro-fused without unlaminating.

You should unroll a couple times to reduce loop overhead.  You should combine the pointer-increment with the loop counter so you `cmp/jb` instead of `sub/ja`: macro-fusion on more CPUs, and avoids writing a register (reducing the amount of physical registers needed for register-renaming).

Your inner loop, on Intel Sandybridge/Ivybridge, will run

```
@@To1:
movdqa xmm0, DQWORD PTR [eax]       // 1 uop
pcmpeqw xmm0, DQWORD PTR [eax+edx] // 2 uops on Intel SnB/IvB, 1 on Nehalem and earlier or Haswell and later.
pmovmskb ebx, xmm0                // 1 uop
cmp ebx, 65535
jne @@Final                     // 1 uop  (macro-fused with cmp)
add eax, 16                    // 1 uop
sub ecx, 8
{ AnsiChar  : sub ecx, 16 }
ja @@To1                     // 1 uop (macro-fused with sub on SnB and later, otherwise 2)
```

This is 7 fused-domain uops, so it can only issue from the front-end at best 7/4 cycles per iteration on mainstream Intel CPUs.  This is very far from bottlenecking on 2 loads per clock.  On Haswell and later, it's 6/4 cycles per iteration, because indexed addressing modes can stay micro-fused with 2-operand load-modify instruction like `pcmpeqw`, but not anything else (like `pabsw xmm0, [eax+edx]` (doesn't read destination) or AVX `vpcmpeqw xmm0, xmm0, [eax+edx]` (3 operands)).  See [Micro fusion and addressing modes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26046634/micro-fusion-and-addressing-modes#comment76198723_31027695).

---

**This could be more efficient for small strings with better setup/cleanup, too.**

In your pointer-setup code, you could save a `cmp` if you check for NULL pointers first.  You can `sub` / `jne` to subtract *and* check for both equal with the same macro-fused compare and branch.  (It will only macro-fuse on Intel Sandybridge-family, and only Haswell can make 2 macro-fusions in a single decode block.  But Haswell/Broadwell/Skylake CPUs are common and becoming ever more common, and this has no downside for other CPUs unless equal-pointers is so common that doing that check first matters.)

---

In your return path: Always use [`xor eax,eax` to zero a register](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33666617/what-is-the-best-way-to-set-a-register-to-zero-in-x86-assembly-xor-mov-or-and) whenever possible, not `mov eax, 0`.

You don't seem to avoid reading from past the end of the string.  You should test your function with strings that end right at the end of a page, where the next page is unmapped.

`xor ebx, [eax + edx]` has zero advantages over `cmp` for the early-out scalar test.  `cmp/jnz` can macro-fuse with the jcc, but `xor` can't.

---

You load a mask to handle the cleanup to cover the case where you read past the end of the string.  You could probably still use the usual `bsf` to find the first difference in the bitmap.  I guess invert it with `not` to find the first position that didn't compare equal, and check that that's less than the remaining string length.

Or you could generate the mask on the fly with `mov eax, -1` and `shr`, I think.  Or for loading it, you can sometimes use a sliding window into a `...,0,0,0,-1,-1,-1,...` array, but you need sub-byte offsets so that doesn't work.  (It works well for vector masks, if you wanted to mask and redo the `pmovmskb`.  [Vectorizing with unaligned buffers: using VMASKMOVPS: generating a mask from a misalignment count? Or not using that insn at all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34306933/vectorizing-with-unaligned-buffers-using-vmaskmovps-generating-a-mask-from-a-m)).

Your way isn't bad, as long as it doesn't cache miss.  I'd probably go for generating the mask on the fly.  Maybe *before* the loop in another register, because you can mask to get `count % 8`, so the mask-generation can happen in parallel with the loop.

Comment: Thank you. I was able to speed up

Comment: You mention to _use the implicit-length versions in your main loop when you're not close to the end of the string._ - but how do you actually do for `memcmp` where the memory many contain 0 values which shouldn't be treated specially? It seems like you'd always be spuriously hitting the "end" of the string when either vector had a zero and then need some fallback path to do a 0-insensitive compare. The user does have the word `strcmp` at the top of the code, but they are known length-strings, so it's like a `memcmp` other than taking 16-bits at a time.

Comment: Your uop counting in the code following the "Your inner loop, on Intel Haswell, will run" part is in fused uops, right? I'm quite sure that `pcmpeq` family is 1 fused uops rather than 2 on Haswell, SnB, etc - and Agner's guide seems to confirm it (of course, it's 2 unfused uops like all memory source instructions other than `mov` and a few variants).

Comment: I've found the SSE4.2 string instructions to almost be useless in a lot of cases when you'd intuitively think it's useful. The combination of, `pcmpeqb` + `pmovmaskb` + `bsf`/`tzcnt` will do pretty much everything you'd normally need on strings. The only case where I found it useful was when I needed the mask in a SIMD register. Then the SSE4.2 string instructions let you avoid the round-trip to the GPRs.

Comment: @BeeOnRope: You're right, Haswell will keep it micro-fused without un-laminating, because it's the special case of a load-modify (unlike `pabsb xmm0, [eax+edx]` which would un-laminate).  SnB/IvB will un-laminate even `pcmpeqw`.  Agner's microarch guide is wrong, and omits un-lamination.  Updated my answer with a link to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26046634/micro-fusion-and-addressing-modes#comment76198723_31027695.

Comment: @mysticial - the "find any match in any position" (essentially 16 parallel checks against 16 bytes) functionality is pretty cool, when it applies and hard to emulate (you have to use 16 `cmpeq` instructions or something?). Still even that's falling behind as vector length has increased to 256 and now 512 bits with no increase in the string instruction lengths. That combined with crappy throughput means that even alternatives that take a dozen instructions or more are viable.

Comment: @BeeOnRope: Good point, but if your code doesn't have any other AVX512 loops, using it at all will lower your max turbo for the rest of the program.  Same for AVX2.  Also, for functions that usually deal with short-ish strings, wide vectors loops often have more startup/cleanup overhead.

Comment: @peter - sure, yes. It's still means the use case for the SSE4.2 string instructions is just being narrowed further: if such ops are really important, you'll be using larger-width AVX. Many people (and increasing with time) will indirectly be using  higher width SIMD due to dispatching library functions and in some cases compiler generated code (for recent enough `march`). Down clocking for AVX2 is far from universal: it's essentially absent from deployed client cores, for example.

Comment: The future isn't clear though and the point is a good one but far more general: compilers and developers seem to have basically zero support and haven't spent much time thinking about this "higher level" meta-optimization where you basically have to decide up front whether your entire codebase (or at least some large chunk at runtime) can use extensions A, B, C, etc. Every discussion of a small function now has to be conditioned on the caveat about turbo frequencies, and we haven't even talked about how the scales slide with active cores!