# In x86-64, does the pcmpestri instruction take its length arguments in RAX and RDX in units of characters or in bytes?

Tags: assembly, x86

That is, if characters are 16-bit words, is the value of RAX and RDX in units of 1 = 1 16-bit character or is it the number of bytes?

I posted this question earlier in another post, and Peter Cordes was kind enough to reply, saying that he like me had not seen an example of the use with words. I am posting this question on its own so it has improved visibility, rather than being buried in a mound of other small questions.

Many thanks

Comment: https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/pcmpestri says "number of bytes/words" so that suggests that when using words, it is a count of words.

Comment: Thanks Nate, so we’re thinking word counts for a count of 1.

Comment: I don't think I've *seen* an example that used words instead of bytes, but there's no mystery about how lengths work for that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read [Intel's manual's description](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/pcmpestri), it's pretty much 100% clear:

> The length of each input is interpreted as being the absolute-value of the value in the length register. The absolute-value computation **saturates to 16 (for bytes) and 8 (for words)**, based on the value of imm8[bit3] when the value in the length register is greater than 16 (8) or less than -16 (-8).

This only makes any sense if the units are words for word mode, otherwise you could only use the low 8 bytes of the XMM input registers.

Also, other parts of the description use `16 (8)`, like some I quoted in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63024213) to your previous question.

Comment: Thank you very much indeed Peter. Your help is once again very much appreciated. Pain drugs yesterday made things a bit fuzzy so your help in locating that answer was invaluable.

Comment: @CecilWard: Sorry to hear you're not feeling well.  SSE4.2 string instructions are mind-bending enough with a clear head; if you're not feeling 100% it might be more productive to work on something else, especially if you run into more problems grokking something. :/

Comment: I’m afraid it’s a permanent condition. But a small challenge helps keep my mind off the pain. If I’m too bad then I just rest a while and come back to problems later. Since I used to do asm for a living 35 years ago I’m enjoying this like a visit to an old friend. I have friends who would much prefer to write stuff in C or even D and would want to stay well away from asm so the idea is to write the best ‘intrinsic-like’ access routines for D so that the caller can implement any kind of string application with them but actually I don’t know  exactly what the caller is even doing.

Comment: Yes I see it clearly now in that intel manual. Brilliant. It is indeed quite clear.